# How do I programmatically create a view?

Tags: 7, views

There is a set of products in Drupal Commerce. How do I programmatically create a view that would select products for a particular field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Guidelines on customisation options when using hook\_views\_default\_views?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72272/guidelines-on-customisation-options-when-using-hook-views-default-views)

Comment: I don't think they are duplicates.  The referenced question is asking about `hook_views_default_views()` for *altering an existing view* whereas this Q (seems to be) about creating a View programatically from scratch.

Comment: @Chapabu I trust if I'm mistaken people will vote for this one to stay.

Comment: Not sure OP will return 8 months later and edit this post for better clarification. But it sounds like she was looking for some contextual filter stuff. Not to create a view object.

Answer (score 4):

The classic way is to create it manually, via UI, then click "export" (path like http://example.org/admin/structure/views/view/default_demo/export), and wrap resulting code into a module using [hook_views_default_views()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_default_views/7), maybe fine-tuning details.

Comment: Why did you just repeat my answer?

Comment: @ram4nd not quite repeat. Your answer lacked (and still lack) detailed info where to find export, and was poorly written (edited months after I posted mine).

Comment: That's usually where adding a comment comes in. Usually you only post another answer if there's something fundamentally different about what you're saying.