# How to Get data of Content type in a custom view

Tags: views

I have a content type "tasks", I created a custom view.i want to show all data of content type "tasks" in that custom view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems to be answered already at [How do I programmatically create a view?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52707/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-view). In case you need the reference here is another link http://www.packtpub.com/article/creating-views-3-programmatically
Hope this helps you.

Comment: This link helps me to create a custom view programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/viewsnodefield

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear do you want to the data in View using some custom code, if not u can just go to Structure and then click Views. Then click add a new View. Add a name and select your custom content. In Display format under create a Page,, select Unformatted list of type Field from the the 2nd selection and then press Continue & Edit   at Bottom. Here In Fields section click Add and add all the field relevant to your Content type.

Thanks hope that helps you. Click it if the answer is relevant to you.

Comment: Yes, i want the data in view using custom code.