# How do I programmatically create a view whose structure is defined at runtime?

Tags: 7, views

I know I am able to create a view programatically here: ["How do I programatically create a view?"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52707/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-view) - only this requires knowing the structure of the view (e.g. which fields / filters / relationships to use) already.

How can I dynamically create a view at runtime?  Either the view would get stored in the same place as typical views (in the views database) - or it could exist 'In code' except the code is dynamically generated.  E.g. is it possible just to create views ad hoc in `hook_views_default_views()`?

Comment: Yeah absolutely, the Views module isn't bothered about how you build up the objects/arrays in `hook_views_default_views()`, you can build it dynamically or statically, totally your choice

Comment: ok - but do you know if this gets cached?

Comment: I jsut checked and it does - so if I were to go down this route, I would need to be able to reset the cache somehow if my views structure changed

Comment: Exactly right, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - no answers and I've figured out two ways to do this.

**1. hook_views_default_views()**

One way is to define the view in `hook_views_default_views()` and then to rest the cache for instance with `views_invalidate_cache()`. These views end up being 'in code' but not actually set.  This didn't seem like the most desirable method for my use - but might be better for some applications.

**2. save the $view**

Create the view e.g. `$view = new view();` and fill all the fields, and then `$view->save()` saves it to the views database. Keeping a record of the name of the view allows you to delete it later if necessary etc.